# I have an issue installing a python library (with aiohttp)

Tags: python, discord.py, aiohttp

> Building wheel for aiohttp (pyproject.toml) ... error
> error: subprocess-exited-with-error
>
> Building wheel for aiohttp (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
> exit code: 1
> [110 lines of output]`

This is the error I get when in try to install a library with the code `pip install discord.py`
Can someone help me find what this error is about and how can I correct it?

After looking on internet, I have found people downgrading their version of python to make sure that it is compatible. For that, I installed Miniconda and created a new environment where I downloaded the 3.8 version of python (I have the 3.12 on my computer).
But I still get the exact same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see the message `Building wheel for`, it indicates that it is trying to build the package on your computer and not downloading a pre-built package.

You can see in the pypi page of `aiohttp` that the package was not compiled for 3.12, but was only compiled for versions between 3.6 to 3.11 https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp/#files , possibly there is a good reason for that.

You probably are still running with python 3.12 and did not activate the conda environment before trying to run `pip install`. Optionally, you can verify this by running `which pip`, which will show you which pip installation are you running. (If you are using windows, then you can use the `where.exe` instead of the `which` command)

See this for activating the environment: https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment

Answer (score 1):

Double check your python version.

As of writing this `aiohttp` cannot be installed on python 3.12 using a wheel see [here](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/7646)

You may need to download an earlier version of python or you can try install it without pip (therefore without a wheel). see [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-python-libraries-without-using-the-pip-command/)